# How can I update VS Code without getting these errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated my version of VS Code to the October release but I noticed a badge on the settings icons that states `Restart to update`.

I keep getting the error message below when I click the `Restart to update` button

[image: Error message popup 1]

Clicking `Retry` just repeats the cycle over again. Clicking `Cancel` shows another popup as below:

[image]

Would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine? Also, have you checked that no anti-virus software and/or other (VS Code) processes are interfering with the update?

Comment: I have restarted my machine severally, still wasn't fixed. I also have anti-virus software installed but I don't know if they're interfering with the update.

Comment: I'm wondering if another version of VS Code on your machine has a startup daemon or process running in the background causing this conflict.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston This could be but how do I track or kill the other version that might be running in the background. I've actually tried a lot of things, but all to no avail

Comment: Open up the Windows Task Manager and scroll to Background Processes. If that doesn't work, you may just have to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: If you're comfortable with PowerShell, you could also use the `Stop-Process` cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6